# Should I close a file before moving it?

Tags: python

I have code like this:

```
with open('foo.txt') as file:
    ...do something with file...
    ...move foo.txt to another place while it's still open...
```

Are there any problems with that?

Comment: Are you only reading the file (the code would suggest that is the case)?  If writing you will have problems.  You might get different effect depending on the operating system, and whether you are moving to a different directory or partition.  Please give more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the operating system. In Unix-based systems this is generally safe (you can move or even delete file while still having it open). Windows will produce Access Denied error if you try to move/delete an opened file.

So yes, the safest and portable way is to close the file first. Note that `with` clause closes the file automatically, so all you need is to perform the move *outside* of `with` block.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open('old.txt') as file:
        os.rename('old.txt', 'new.txt')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
    os.rename('test.txt', 'newtest.txt')
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

You can't move the file, because someone(you) is already holding it. You need to close the file before you can move it.

Comment: Does this apply to Unix too?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice with `file` is `close` and `move`, because if you will not `close` then it might be create problem in some OS, like `Windows`.

To make your code more portable, `close` file before `move`.

Answer (score 0):

yes , I was getting same issue,
I was doing some operation in for loop(if rows/content is valid then move destination folder)
outside for loop, if no header/no content/no rows then move to error folder
and I was getting error
I could resolve it using "read_obj.close" jus before filemove method
here is the snippet
with open(csv_file, 'r') as read_obj:

```
                # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
                csv_dic_reader = csv.DictReader(read_obj)
                data = [row for row in csv_dic_reader]
                for row in data:
                    read_obj.close()
                    filesMove(csv_file, destination_file_path, src_file_path)
            if len(data) <= 1: # this will check no rows/content
            read_obj.close()
            filesMove(csv_file, error_file_path, src_file_path)
```